# A-sync Speed over Gigabit LAN Ethernet File Transfer

Tags: file, performance, ethernet, transfer, lan

I have a strange problem with transferring files between 2 computers connected to each other through an ethernet cable. Both PCs have on-board gigabit ethernet ports. Aside from the different hardwares, the softwares (especially network settings) are configured almost the same, with Windows 7 x64 etc. Tests have been taken with and without antivirus programs running with no difference. Duplex settings are auto negotiation. Jumbo packets (~9MB) are enabled (usually I'm transferring really large files). Hard drives are not a problem, since local transfer speed within a computer is around 100 MB/s.

Now if I am on PC1, and accessing shared files on PC2: Transferring files from PC1 to PC2 is very fast, usually in the range of 60 MB/s (see results below from LAN SpeedTest). But the opposite (transferring from PC2 to PC1) is really slow, about 10 MB/s.
[Speed Test 1](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/6323/pc1y.jpg)

If I am on PC2, and accessing PC1: Transferring files from PC2 to PC1 is slow (see speed test below - it's actually a little slower than when I'm transferring files and reading the speed report from Windows), while the opposite is fast (also about 60 MB/s like in the first case)
(I would post link 2 here but it does not allow me to since I am new)

So what causes this?

TIA

Comment: Here is the link to Speed Test 2 that I mentioned above: http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/7378/pc2v.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It might have to do with the hard drive write speed of PC1.  The read speed is fast enough to send data to PC2, but the write speed is not fast enough to receive the data from PC2.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly question but when you say the computers are connected via an Ethernet cable do you mean directly connected or via a switch?  If directly connected, are you using a crossover Ethernet cable or straight-through cable? If using a straight-through cable, I would say that one or both of the cards are failing to auto-sense if they have that capability.  Also auto-duplex and auto-speed settings have been known to fail in the past, try setting them manually as well.

Comment: I am connecting them directly with a straight through cable. I can't set the speed at 1000Mbps manually because there is no such setting (only 10, 100, then auto). Anyway, how do you explain the speed difference (fast in 1 direction and slow in the other)? If some packet is able to be transferred at 60 MB/s, I would guess that both ports are functioning quite well (otherwise, the one not functioning correctly would hinder the speed of the faster one, right?)

Comment: The speed appears to be consistently fast in only one direction which is from PC1 to PC2.  On an Ethernet cable on 10/100 Mb/s networks, sending happens on one pair and receiving happens on a different pair. On gigabit networks, sending and receiving are suppose to happen on all pairs and a crossover cable is no longer required if I understand the spec correctly. One would think that if one port was performing slower than the other then it would affect traffic in both directions however the receiver only needs to send an ACK. It is always slow from PC2 to PC1, I would suspect PC2 or the cable.

Comment: Since PC2 to PC1 transfers are always slow, grab a crossover cable, set the speed manually to 100 and full duplex on both, and redo the speed tests.  If the results are similar, i.e. PC2 to PC1 fails or is still only 10Mb/s, then start suspecting the hardware on PC2.

Comment: As a side note the gigabit standard requires auto-crossover.